JPA Repository search by field input from the user form
I have a form in Angular which looks like so

The user can input only the field he wants and I send the form to Spring Rest API like so
{
    "symbol": "DOL",
    "currency": "CAD"
}

From there how to redirect the JPA repository query. I mean if the user only select symbol then the query will be findAllBySymbol ; if the user select the symbol AND the currency then the query should be findAllBySymbolAndCurrency.
How to approach this? Should I query all and filter out? That does not sound optimal

Querying all and then filtering in the application is more work in terms of sending more data from database to the application,  then processing and returning to the web client. In general, doing all the process you can  on the database server is recommended. Database queries can also use indexes in searches.

but how would you direct the jpa query as some field might be undefined, you cannot check all the combinations of fields in a switch

Maybe check what fields have values and direct to the specific query. Even build a native or JPQL query (using @Query annotation).

You can achieve that using specifications.
In order to do that, first extend your repository with the SpecificationExecutor
public interface YourRepository extends JpaRepository<YourEntity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<YourEntity> {
}

In order to easily work with the specifications, it's advised to add the `jpa-modelgen' dependency:
(for gradle groovy)
annotationProcessor('org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:6.5.1.Final')

Then, define the specifications that will be used for the search:
public class YourSpecifications {
    private YourSpecifications() {
    }

    public static Specification<YourEntity> byCurrency(String currency) {
        return (root, query, builder) -> currency != null ? builder.equal(root.get(MoneyEntity_.SYMBOL), currency) : builder.and();

    }

    public static Specification<YourEntity> bySymbol(String symbol) {
        return (root, query, builder) -> symbol != null ? builder.equal(root.get(MoneyEntity_.SYMBOL), symbol) : builder.and();
    }
}

Once that's configured, you can start using the repository by using i.e. findAll or findOne methods:
return repository.findAll(
                YourSpecifications.byCurrency(currency)
                .and(YourSpecifications.bySymbol(symbol))
        );

In the example null is checked within the specification, so that if the symbol is null (not provided), all the results are returned. This should be adapted to your needs.
In order to explore the specifications in more details, check out the spring docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/jpa/specifications.html, as well as jpa criteria API https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/3.2.2/apache-openjpa/docs/#jpa_overview_criteria

A bit more details with regards to the dependency required for Maven
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

